# Do we want hats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

[In 2011, the Gaming Stack Exchange hosted an event called Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/), where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges):

[image]

Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

This year, Stack Exchange is expanding the promotion to any site that wants to participate.

Here's the run down:

- The event will run from 19 December 2012 to 4 January 2013.
- Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterba.sh. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
- Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option available.
- The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

We need to let Stack Exchange know by 28 November 2012, so vote away on if you want hats.

<sup>(This has been shamelessly stolen from [Programmers SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5240/69203).)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there seems to be no objection, I'll be communicating the team about our participation.

Answer (score 2):

Why not, seems to be fun. I once made my own hat (atop of my default gravatar).

Comment: Yes me too, last year. :)